# Changing a Tiled Texture model to clip Texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv

First post here. New to blender

I am working with 8 materials that I have to combine into one. The object has each material as a simple repeating tiled texture and a detailed UV map that goes out of texture bounds. This is what one of the materials look like.
[image]

This made Texture Atlasing seem impossible. Are there any solutions?

Is Virtual Photogrammetry possible? Exporting the sword's already aligned texture by scanning it

Comment: You might look into baking the texture onto the object.

Comment: @AxiDes I tried but it didn't help with majority of the UV being outside the texture. Setting it to clip instead of repeat meant that the majority of the material would not be textured either